# Обновление Spinnera налету из коллекции

Tags: java, android

Как я уже понял, спиннер обновить легко и просто не получится. 
 У меня при включении в него загружается вот этот пустой List

```
List<String> currencies =  new ArrayList<>();
```

Далее подгружается из сети новый список и где то в методе

```
    currencies.clear();
    currencies.addAll(Data.getCurrencies());
    Collections.sort(currencies);
```

Выполнить обновление не могу из этого метода, только в `onCreate` срабатывает

```
SpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Но тем не менее если кликнуть на спиннер , то там есть тот самый загруженный массив, но поле где стоит выбранная позиция, пустое и если что то выбрать, то там все равно ничего не появляется.
  И что интересно при запросе нового списка, у меня нормально срабатывает этот код  (не дебажил, но вроде нет экспешена)

```
    currencies.clear();
    currencies.addAll(Data.getCurrencies());
    Collections.sort(currencies);
```

Пробую по другому: изначально массив теперь делаю не пустым

```
List<String> currencies = Arrays.asList("AUD", "BGN")
```

спиннер в onCreate успевает заполниться, но следом вызывается код и на любой из этих строчек  неизвестное исключение.

```
    currencies.clear();
    currencies.addAll(Data.getCurrencies());
    Collections.sort(currencies);
```

Может я массив изначально как то не так объявил?...

Читал про Cursor Loader и заполнение с использованием промежуточной строки, но вроде они отношение имеют только к загрузке спиннера из базы данных.

Вот адаптер , он в onCreate в активити создается.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> SpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currencies); //Адаптер для спиннера

SpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        SpinnerOfCurrencies.setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter);
        SpinnerOfCurrencies.setSelection(currencies.indexOf("EUR"));
```

//Обработчик нажатия на спиннер

```
 SpinnerOfCurrencies.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff8800")); //Цвет текста выбранной позиции в спинере
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(18);
            CurrentCurrency(position);
            UploadData();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList("AUD", "BGN")` создаёт немутабельную коллекцию. Её нельзя менять. Оберните в `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("AUD", "BGN"));`. А про обновление надо подробнее - покажите больше контектста обновления и сам адаптер.

Comment: Вот , не знал я про неизменные коллекции. В принципе проблема решена, если я изначально задаю в спиннер не пустую коллекцию, то в еще не нажатом спиннере отображается и при обновлении , если нажать на спиннер видно , что появились результаты которых не было. А вот если изначально задать пустой спиннер, то и при обновлении хоть результаты и появляются, но выбранный пункт не отображается в TextView спиннера

Comment: Сперва инициализирую пустую коллекцию. Создаю адаптер. Нажатием на кнопку идет загрузка по сети и выполняется код добавления в коллекцию строк.  Но notifyDataSetChanged() не выполняю ибо он только в onCreate сущетсвует, из других методов класса у адаптера такого метода нет.    Ну и теперь спиннер пополнился , можно выбрать что то , но это не отображается.

Comment: для сетевых запросов можно использовать AsyncTaskLoader, а не CursorLoader. Если ваш запрос на основе AsyncTask (а не какой нибудь Retrofit) то использование лоудера настоятельно рекомендуется

Comment: Ну да , у меня через AsyncTask, но вроде бы и без лоудера работает. Просто если задать пустым коллекцию, а потом заполнить, то выбранный элемент не отображается, хотя методы о том что выбрана какая то позиция отрабатывают.

Comment: лоудер решает несколько важных проблем (в частности сохранение состояния при повороте устройства), если вы почитаете о его назначении, то и сами поймете, что он вам нужен.

Comment: _Но notifyDataSetChanged() не выполняю ибо он только в onCreate сущетсвует, из других методов класса у адаптера такого метода нет._ Быть такого не может. Или у вас все остальные методы статические?

Comment: @eugeneek скорее адаптер инициализирован, как локальная переменная в методе onCreate(), а не полем класса, вот и "не доступен" в других методах

Comment: @pavlofff Да, кстати, может и так. Смутила формулировка, что внутри одного метода, метод объекта виден, а внутри других - нет)

Comment: Вот что значит не спать и кодить. У меня оказывается спиннер глобальный, а вот адаптер только в onCreate. Только не знаю зачем мне нужен этот метод notifyDataSetChanged(), если без него всё обновляется. А когда его запускаю  в конце после обновления хранящихся в спиннера данных , то сбрасывается на белый цвет выбранного элемента.  Цвет устанавливается в обработчике нажатия, я его к  вопросу добавил.

Comment: На мгновение после выбора ставится нужный цвет и снова белый.

Comment: Теперь, если поставить в адаптер пустую коллекцию, а после заполнить и нажать на спиннер там всё появляется, но выбранный пункт не устанавливается в спиннер, если сделать еще и notifyDataSetChanged() , то выбранный пункт устанавливается в спиннер (отображается) , но цвет его только на мгновение становится нужным, а потом снова белый

Comment: Сделаю отдельный вопрос по этому поводу